# Speeding up ComplexExpand

Tags: performance-tuning, complex, algebraic-manipulation

I have a code where I have to take the dot product of two lists, that contain some symbols, and then use `ComplexExpand`. For a long list it take a very long time and I would like to speed it up.

Here is a minimum working example. My actual code can be more complicated. I start by making a list of mixed random complex numbers and some symbols:

```
nn = 1000;
SeedRandom[123];
a = Table[
   RandomComplex[] + a0 +
    RandomComplex[] (a1 + I b1) + RandomComplex[] (a1 - I b1) +
    RandomComplex[] (a2 + I b2) + RandomComplex[] (a2 - I b2),
   {nn}];
```

Now I come to the slow part

```
b = ComplexExpand[Re[a . Conjugate[a]]]; // Timing

(*  {1.01563, Null} *)
```

Any ideas on how to speed this up?

Thanks

**Edit**

This suggestion

```
Timing[Total[ComplexExpand[ReIm[a]^2], 2];]
```

(* {2.28125, Null} *)

Makes the timing worse

Comment: What happens if you do `Total[ComplexExpand[ReIm[a]^2], 2]` instead?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the idea, however it makes things worse. Pity. See edit

Comment: That is unfortunate indeed. I presume you have no easy way of separately computing the real and imaginary parts of `a`?

Comment: @J.M. I have been working on that but no ideas yet.

Comment: Do the expressions always have this structure?

Comment: @Carl similar but more terms.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe just conjugate explicitly?

```
nn = 1000;
SeedRandom[123];
aa = Table[
   RandomComplex[] + a0 + RandomComplex[] (a1 + I b1) + 
    RandomComplex[] (a1 - I b1) + RandomComplex[] (a2 + I b2) + 
    RandomComplex[] (a2 - I b2), {nn}];

Timing[
 aa2 = Chop[Expand[aa.(aa /. Complex[r_, i_] :> Complex[r, -i])]];]

(* Out[473]= {0.53125, Null} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get a 3x speedup by manufacturing your own complex functions:

```
af[n_] := 
 BlockRandom[
  Table[RandomComplex[] + a0 + RandomComplex[] (a1 + I b1) + 
    RandomComplex[] (a1 - I b1) + RandomComplex[] (a2 + I b2) + 
    RandomComplex[] (a2 - I b2), {n}], RandomSeeding -> 123]

bf[z_] := ComplexExpand[Re[z . Conjugate[z]]] // Timing

xf[n_] := 
 BlockRandom[
  Table[RandomComplex[] + a0 + RandomComplex[] (a1 + I b1) + 
     RandomComplex[] (a1 - I b1) + RandomComplex[] (a2 + I b2) + 
     RandomComplex[] (a2 - I b2), {n}] /. {Complex[r_, i_] -> 
     r + cu i}, RandomSeeding -> 123]

yf[z_] := 
 Expand[Dot[z, z /. {cu -> -cu}]] /. {cu^2 -> -1, cu^3 -> -cu , 
    cu^4 -> 1, cu -> 0} // Timing

check = With[{data = 
    Table[{n, bf[af[n]], 
      yf[xf[n]]}, {n, {100, 500, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000}}]},
  GraphicsRow[{ListLogLogPlot[{#[[1]], #[[3, 1]]/#[[2, 1]]} & /@ 
      data, PlotLabel -> "Ratio of timing"], 
    ListLogLinearPlot[ {#[[1]], Chop[#[[3, 2]] - #[[2, 2]]]} & /@ 
      data, PlotLabel -> "Difference of values"]}]
  ]
```

[image: plot]